# Is the use of id type in method a good practice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api

I am creating a set of API and some users have suggested that I use id type for a particular method that can accept custom object (defined by the API) or string instead of creating two versions.  Is the use of id type in method a good or acceptable practice? Does Apple do it with their any of their API?

Comment: It depends on the API. The question can't be answered without the actual specifics of what the API does.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe As mentioned, the API method can only work with NSString or a custom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be very poor practice.  If you're creating an API you need to retain full control, and allowing users to pass any object to your method at which point you would have to cast it to that object or string you mentioned could be fatal depending on what's passed.  Creating two methods with different parameters is not only okay, but follows the tenets of polymorphism to the T.

Comment: `-[NSMutableArray addObject:]` is an example for proper use of `id` in a well designed API (within the constraints of Objective-C).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe true, but it makes no difference what type of object NSMutableArray holds, whereas if Boon receives one type, when he expects another, his program may well crash if proper precautions aren't taken.  That's why it would just be easier to employ polymorphism.

Comment: There's no "type cast" in the Objective runtime. "Types" (fake types, really) only exist at _compile time_ as a facility provided by the compiler to give us (programmers) a clue what kind of objects we apparently deal with and in order to issue certain warnings if there seemingly is a type conflict. The compiler however, can be easily fooled about the actual type. Despite objects having only a unique type (`id`), an object is some sort of "kind", which you can obtain via sending it a message. This is not a "type", though as defined in the "type system" of a language.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting `id` is not in itself good or bad practice. How much manual procedural if/then/else/if/then/else nonsense will you acquire? If quite a lot then something is wrong.

Put another way: if the conditional logic related to different kinds of object ends up being implicit, via the Objective-C dispatch mechanisms, then the design is good. If you end up impliedly reimplementing dynamic dispatch then you've gone completely wrong.

Apple does it frequently. Just off the top of my head there are:

- as per Nikolai's comment, all the collection types: set, dictionary, array, etc.
- anything that takes `%@` as a format specifier: `NSLog`, certain methods on `NSString`, etc.
- anything that still uses an informal protocol.
- anything in or semi-close to the runtime like key-value coding.
- archiving and the user defaults.
- anywhere that storage is offered for your own use — the hardy `userInfo` on `NSTimer` and the rest.
- anywhere that target/action is used — all `UIControl`s, the notification centre, etc.

As per my comment, suppose your custom class had this method:

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

And suppose it were the only method being called by whomever is being passed either a string or your custom object. Then `id` would be the right choice, since you'd have in effect implemented an informal protocol, and the thing being passed an object genuinely doesn't care whether it's a string or not. The only contractual requirement is the informal protocol and the protocol is informal i.e. has no footprint on the type syntax.

Conversely, suppose your custom class had no methods in common with NSString and your code just looked like:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)object
{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        [self myMethodOnString:object];
    else
        [self myMethodOnCustomClass:object];
}
```

Then `id` would be inappropriate. You're just obscuring what the method does and implicitly reproducing work that's built into the runtime anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tommy - what methods in NSString takes id?

Comment: As per `NSLog`, anything to which you've supplied a `%@` formatter. `NSString`'s going to call `description` on the thing regardless; it doesn't need to know the type. So the conditional statements necessary to decide how to print are effected implicitly by the runtime. It ends up being an informal protocol.

Comment: Tommy, per your note on "Accepting id is not in itself good or bad practice" - I would like to know if accepting id is good for my API - which I stated that it only works with NSString and a custom object, unlike the ones you list, which can work with all objects.  Thanks.

Comment: @Boon that's still not enough information. Supposing your custom object responded to `-dataUsingEncoding:` such that to the caller it made no difference whatsoever whether it was calling an `NSString` or not. Then `id` would be the correct type to use. The information you give isn't enough to say a definite yes or no and, as a policy, there's no absolute definite yes or no.

Comment: I think there is enough info - the fact that the call only accepts string or custom object means that you cannot pass in anything else but those two, so you can automatically assume that within the custom object, the behavior is no less strict - otherwise, what's the reason for the restriction at the outer level?